# The image is not shown when merging two images in PHP GD library in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, gdlib, imagecreatefrompng

I got this code to work but after few weeks the code is not working ,i did try to see where the bug come from but i have no idea.
I did create image with GD library and it is created successfully but when i want to merge it with another picture it show only black screen.Any idea of how to solve the issue please .Here is my code:
Please note that the image is created and saved successfully,so there is no problem with create_image() function.

```
function create_image()
{
    $cer_id = get_the_ID();
    $cer_org_nummer = get_field('orgnummer_dqm');
    $cer_today = date('Y-m-d');
    $cer_org_name = get_field('foretags_namn_dqm');
    $cer_org_date = $cer_org_nummer . ' | ' . $cer_today;


    $im = @imagecreate(500, 450);
    $yellow = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);  // yellow
    imagecolortransparent($im, $yellow);

    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 252, 195, 91);
    $string = "Digital Quality Managment";
    $font = FUNC_PLUGIN_D_DQM . '/font/Roboto-Regular.ttf';// black

    /*    imagestring($im, $font, 50, 300, $string, $black);*/
    /*    imagestring($im, $font, 3, 300, $cer_org_name, $black);*/
    /*    imagestring($im, $font, 0, 10, $cer_org_date, $black);*/
    imagettftext($im, 35, 0, 60, 270, $black, $font, 'CERTIFIED');

    imagettftext($im, 25, 0, 0, 320, $black, $font, $cer_org_date);

    imagepng($im, "wp-content/plugins/certificates/cer_images/image_$cer_id.png");
    imagedestroy($im);
}
      create_image();
    $image1 = "wp-content/plugins/certificates/cer_images/dqm_png_logo.png";
    $image2 = "wp-content/plugins/certificates/cer_images/image_$cer_id.png";

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image2);


    $image1 = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image1));

    $image2 = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image2));


    imagealphablending($image1, FALSE);
    imagesavealpha($image1, TRUE);
    imagecopymerge($image1, $image2, 110, 50, 0, 0, $width, $height, 100);


    header("Content-type: image/png");
    imagepng($image1);
    imagedestroy($image1);
```

Comment: Hi
i have also used same type of code to merge 2 images, and its working fine on my end. i m using that code from more then 4 months...
If u want then i will share my code with you

Comment: Thank you,please share it with me. @YogeshGarg

Comment: HI @AmjadKhalil
please check the code added in Answer section..
Here **$_REQUEST['apid']** is id image.
You need to use the directory path of image for this functionality.

Comment: @YogeshGarg Thank you but that did not work,i guess some thing wrong with the theme because my code used to work few days before but it start to not work after i updated the theme.

Comment: ok.. then please check you code once.. if you need any help then please let me know.

Comment: @YogeshGarg Thank you,I do really appreciate your help.I did solved the issue.There were no problem with the code.The problem was from the server .I did just update the php version on it and then every thing works fine.Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try the code below

This code works for me..

```
$pro_directory_path = get_attached_file( get_post_thumbnail_id($_REQUEST['apid']),'full' );

$mainmetadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata( get_post_thumbnail_id( $_REQUEST['apid'] ) );

$pro_img_name = $mainmetadata['file'];

$pro_img_name_extra = '1'.$mainmetadata['file'];

// $val_id is id of image(bigger image/background Image)
$directory_path = get_attached_file( $val_id,'full' );

$metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $val_id );

$name = $metadata['file'];

$bgFile = $directory_path;

// We want our final image to be 76x76 size
//user $metadata to get ordiginal height width of image
// $value contain height width of wall mentioned by admin
$x = $metadata['width'];
$y = $metadata['height'];

$x_inch = $metadata['width']/96;
$y_inch = $metadata['height']/96;

$width_proption = $wall_w_inch/$x_inch;
$height_proption = $wall_h_inch/$y_inch;

$img_pos_x = ($x/2)-($resizedwidth/2);
$img_pos_y = ($y/2)-($resizedheight);

/* Code to generate custom wall images - STart */
$inn_width = ($innerimg_width / $width_proption) * 12 ;
$inn_height = ($innerimg_height / $height_proption) * 12 ;

$resizedFilename = get_template_directory().'/woocommerce/temp_images/cust_'.$pro_img_name;

$img_url_extra =  get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/woocommerce/temp_images/cust_'.$pro_img_name;

//function to resize Artist product image in desired size's (Variation sizes).
$imgData = resize_image($pro_directory_path, $inn_width, $inn_height);
imagepng($imgData, $resizedFilename);

list($resizedwidth, $resizedheight) = getimagesize($resizedFilename);

/* Code to generate custom wall images - ENDS */

$imageFile = $resizedFilename;

// dimensions of the final image
$final_img = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y);

// Create our image resources from the files
$image_1 = imagecreatefrompng($bgFile);
$image_2 = imagecreatefrompng($imageFile);

// Enable blend mode and save full alpha channel
imagealphablending($final_img, true);
imagesavealpha($final_img, true);

// Copy our image onto our $final_img
imagecopy($final_img, $image_1, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x, $y);
imagecopy($final_img, $image_2, $img_pos_x, $img_pos_y, 0, 0, $resizedwidth, $resizedheight);

ob_start();
$path =  __DIR__ .'/custom_wall_img/'.$name;
imagepng($final_img,$path);
$watermarkedImg = ob_get_contents(); // Capture the output
ob_end_clean(); // Clear the output buffer
```